# How to open link in safari browser in my ipad sencha app

Tags: sencha-architect

I made a app in sencha architect 2 for magazine reader, now I put link on social icon in my app.

When I click on that social icon, its opening in my app but I want to open it in default browser.

I build my app using http://build.phonegapp.com

Can anyboday help me how to open link in extarnal browser.
Any Example that help????

Comment: Is it opening inside an Inappbrowser/childbrowser?

Comment: Could this help? http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/open_a_link_in_external_browser_for_ios_using_config_xml